# Unexplained VBA overflow error when reading into an array

Tags: excel, vba

newbie here with a perplexing problem of Overflow error with vba

I am populating an array which is dimensioned as variant, with three data pieces per row

```
With ActiveSheet
    For n = 2 To EndRow 'For each data row in the raw data sheet
        rawreadtime = .Cells(n, 1).Value 'Read time into array
        rawreadvol = .Cells(n, 8).Value 'Read corrected volume
        rawreadtest = .Cells(n, 3).Value 'Read which experiment number the data is for
        rawreadcounter = .Cells(n, 7).Value 'Read the number of bucket tips

Debug.Print "rawreadtest = "; rawreadtest; "rawreadcounter = "; rawreadcounter; "rawreadtime = "; rawreadtime


        RawData(1, rawreadtest, rawreadcounter) = rawreadtime 'Load the time data into the raw data array
        RawData(2, rawreadtest, rawreadcounter) = rawreadvol 'Load the volume data into the raw data array
    Next
End With
```

The array dimensions are 
1 to 2, 1 to NumTests (=7), 1 to MaxCounter (=133)

The values of the array indices are :

1; rawreadtest =  4; rawreadcounter =  1;

The data I am reading in is rawreadtime = 20/03/2017 21:56:51

The code falls over at the first "Rawdata(1, .....)".  If I comment out that line the next line works just fine.

This has been working for weeks and now falls over with the overflow error.  I suspect somehow its because we have more data now than I had before but can't be sure.

Any ideas please very gratefully received.

Comment: Given the parameters and code you've provided it works fine on my side. Re-check your code as you've missed something. That or provide a more full example of the code including the dims. Edit: pastebin of functional test sub http://pastebin.com/iH7y0DCt

Comment: Tried to show the code with the dimensions added but don't seem to be able to.

Comment: Tried to show the code with the dimensions added but don't seem to be able to.

All data are dimensioned as Variant in case I've got some funnies in the data, the array is dimensioned as variant, but then there is a redim statement with no data type.  Can't begin to see how that can generate an overflow error - nothing in these is contentious and it used to work yesterday! 

Could it be an OSX Excel problem - as I am discovering that the OSX and Win versions are very different (no decent debugging in OSX)